# Запрос c несколькими базами данных в ORM SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Всем привет! Пересмотрел кучу форумов и документации по SQLAlchemy, но не смог найти нормального примера принципа реализации запроса ниже в одной сессии. Просьба помочь, очень не хотелось бы писать это не через ORM.

```
select a.field1, a.field2, b.field2
from database1.schema1.table_a as a inner join database2.schema1.table_b as b on a.fileld1 = b.fileld1
```

Подключение использую с виндовой аутентификацией:

```
db1_engine1 = create_engine("mssql+pyodbc://@{Server}/{Database}?driver=SQL+Server?trusted_connection=yes")
```

До этого, работал с одной базой и все было ок.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На англоязычной версии дали ответ на мой вопрос, вот пример:
Ссылка на конкретное место в tutorial: [multipart-schema-names](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/mssql.html#multipart-schema-names)

```
n [8]: class TableA(Base):
   ...:     __tablename__ = 'table_a'
   ...:     __table_args__ = {
   ...:         'schema': 'database1.schema1'
   ...:     }
   ...:     id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
   ...:     field1 = Column(Integer)
   ...:     field2 = Column(Integer)
   ...:     

In [9]: class TableB(Base):
   ...:     __tablename__ = 'table_b'
   ...:     __table_args__ = {
   ...:         'schema': 'database2.schema1'
   ...:     }
   ...:     id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
   ...:     field1 = Column(Integer)
   ...:     field2 = Column(Integer)
   ...:     

In [10]: q = session.query(TableA.field1, TableA.field2, TableB.field2).\
    ...:     join(TableB, TableA.field1 == TableB.field1)

In [12]: q.statement.compile(dialect=mssql.dialect())
Out[12]: <sqlalchemy.dialects.mssql.base.MSSQLCompiler at 0x7fa3886027b8>

In [13]: print(_)
SELECT database1.schema1.table_a.field1, database1.schema1.table_a.field2, database2.schema1.table_b.field2 
FROM database1.schema1.table_a JOIN database2.schema1.table_b ON database1.schema1.table_a.field1 = database2.schema1.table_b.field1
```